# mocha: Cannot read property 'be' of undefined

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, chai

I'm writing unit test for my project. But I always meet this problem

Cannot read property 'be' of undefined.

I have a test suite called model-xxx, and I wanna try each method in this model. So each method I write a sub test suite in model-xxx. like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMf7D.jpg)

And each method is related with mongoose, so I hope these sub suite will be async. so each method I write `done()` in `before` and `after` and `it`

but none of these suite passed. error like this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtHiY.jpg)

and like this:

`Cannot read property 'not' of undefined.`

why this occurs? does this mean something wrong with my `should.js`? but it doesn't make sense

hope for solutions.

Comment: the code is here: https://github.com/THCloud/MeanPro/blob/master/test/server/models/test-tag.js

Comment: Please add at least _some_ of your code to your question in textual form, and errors as well, instead of using images.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Chai's `should` is a *function* that needs to be called before you can use should-style assertions:

```
var should = require('chai').should();
```

See [the documentation](http://chaijs.com/guide/styles/#should).

Comment: I write like this before: `var should = require('chai').should;`  it also works sometime...I do add () after should, and modified some code, it works! awesome!